# Performance impact of using Colon vs Dot for function declarations in large lua tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

I've developed the habit of declaring almost all of my modules' functions with a colon rather than a dot, but I don't use much OOP and almost never use "self".
It seems redundant that self gets passed as a parameter every time I call a function, especially if the tables are quite large.

Is there any performance impact with this? Is it worth changing all my function declarations to use a dot?

Comment: It's OK to follow "always use colon syntax" style (even if you don't need `self` inside methods).  This way you will never confuse colon methods with non-colon methods when invoking them. It looks consistent.  For example, [Fengari](https://fengari.io/) imposes "always use colons"  style on all JS objects' methods exposed to Lua.  The performance impact is very small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much of a performance impact to passing a single additional table reference to a function. This is regardless of the table size, as the table doesn't get copied.

Rather than performance, this seems to be a question of programming style. It is very uncommon to use the colon-syntax for module functions, as this idiom is clearly meant to be used for actual method calls. As such, a library that uses it where it's not necessary will look very confusing to any other Lua programmer.

Comment: while colon syntax doesn't really make sense if you're NEVER using self, you might use it if there is a chance that you might use self one day or if you're using it in some methods to make your interface consistent.